# How can I remove the Ubuntu 11.04 disk partition so that there is enough free disk space to install 12.04?

Tags: 11.04, installation, 12.04, partitioning, uninstall

When I installed Ubuntu 11.04 I took the default disk partition size, and it turned out to be too small, so now I'm having problems.

I want to uninstall 11.04 and install 12.04, but unless I can undo the current disk partition and remove 11.04 I can't add another partition large enough to run Ubuntu 12.04.

+Help!

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to " add another partition large enough to run Ubuntu 12.04" as you state?

When you insert the live CD and choose `install Ubuntu` at some point you are asked how the disc lay-out needs to be when installing Ubuntu 12.04.
You can remove 11.04 from there and even remove all partitions and even create new ones.

Only if you need to have some other OS to remain intact you need to be careful not to remove the partitions that OS is on but if their is only 1 OS and it needs to go the installer is the easiest place to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do this, make sure that you are **really** sure that you want to remove Ubuntu 11.10. You will loose all files that you have not backed up. If your intent is to keep all of your files, but upgrade Ubuntu to this newest version, simply run Update Manager from your existing Ubuntu 11.10 installation, and choose to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04. Update Manager allows you to easily upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu while keeping all of you files. If you are sure you want to remove Ubuntu 11.10 instead of upgrading, proceed with the instructions below.

To remove Ubuntu 11.10 from your computer to install Ubuntu 12.04, you will first need a Live Cd or a Live USB. After you boot into it, select Try Ubuntu. Then, you will need to open Gparted, and delete the partition that Ubuntu 11.10 is installed on. Then, you can install Ubuntu 12.04